# import mini DV films from Samsung digital cam VP-D353 [USB]

Tags: 12.04, usb, camera

I tried to import mini DV films from my old video camera (Samsung VP-D353) and it's not recognised by my Lubuntu 12.04 system.

I tried "DVGRAB" which should work, but it doesn't.

I found this tutorial:
http://www.foscode.com/linux-minidv-usb-video-capture/

But it's just saying "waiting for dv".

I don't really know what should I do now. Here is what I've got for the camera when I write `sudo lsub`:

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 04e8:120f Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
```

Comment: Are you sure that your camera can send video via USB? Quite a few miniDV cameras only use the USB function to transfer still images from the SD card. Not sure if yours is one of them. I am facing the same thing with a Canon DV200. I have to go get a firewire card today.

Answer (score 1):

With great exception of some Panasonic miniDV camcorders most miniDV cameras support download of the still images via usb and video via firewire. However even in those cameras where the support of video download and its quality is similar using both protocols the usb2 mode can be used with a special driver mostly available for Windows XP. This implies big problems in Windows Vista, Windows 7, MacOSX, and obviously, and especially in Linux to use this capability. Even finding so-called updated drivers for Windows Vista does not help much since those drivers still work with old video editing software which is only working unfortunately in Windows XP 32 bit and is mostly incompatible with newer Windows versions.